# There seems to have been an unexpected error with Kitematic

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I have installed Docker and for this, I am starting Kitematic and getting the error above. Please find attached screenshot also

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ooCu.png)

Comment: Yeah, me too. Did you find a solution?